# Adding HTML code inside JavaScript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was simply wondering how I would add html code inside a javascript variable? For example, I want to use HTML code (a `<a href="/example.html">` link piece of code) in one of the message lines:

```
var messages = [
"Please wait while we handle your request...",
"This is taking longer than usual to process - please wait...",
"We seem to be having trouble - please click here to contact support"
];

$.each(messages, function(index, message) {
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#wrapper').append(
        $('<p />', {text : message})
    )
}, index * 1500); // 1.5 seconds, add a zero for 15 seconds
});
```

So it would be like:

```
var messages = [
"Please wait while we handle your request...",
"This is taking longer than usual to process - please wait...",
"We seem to be having trouble - please click <a href="/help.html">here</a> to contact support"`
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, you just need to fix the quotes, and use `html` instead of `text`.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you have to:

1. Fix the quotes (`"`) in the string escaping them (`\"`).
2. Use `html:` instead of `text:`.

---

First, edit your `messages` variable like this:

```
var messages = [
    "Please wait while we handle your request...",
    "This is taking longer than usual to process - please wait...",
    "We seem to be having trouble - please click <a href=\"/help.html\">here</a> to contact support"
];
```

Then edit your code to create the `<p>` element like this:

```
 $('<p />', {html : message});
```